# JBoss EAP 6.4 provided libs

Tags: spring, apache-camel, wildfly, jboss6.x

I work on EAP 6.4, Technology Spring boot, Camel and try to make libraries as provided.
Example:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But if I deploy app on EAP dependency doesn't work.

I found way with jboss-deployment-structure.xml where i have defined `<module name="org.apache.camel.core" slot="main"/>`

but I think it should work without this xml.

I dunno what am I doing wrong.

Thx

Comment: I suggest to use wildfly-camel on EAP if you want to run and use Camel on EAP as wildfly-camel is intended for that. This is also what Red Hat Fuse on EAP is supported. https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel